# Blender cycles smoke shader, lighting and shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I was trying to produce a result as shown below using Cycles (youtube clip can be found here ...edit: cant post youtube link as it need more reputation...can search for "Smoke Compilation Blender 2.69 {Experiments & Ideas}" at the 1:39 mark by BeauDG if you are interested).  I recommend watching the clip as one image doesn't really do it justice:

[image: I've attached a screenshot in case you don't want to look at the youtube clip]

My attempt is, and as you can see mine looks less natural and more crappy:

[image: My attempt]

I can only post 2 links so can't show my node setup.  I used one from another tutorial.  My smoke domain settings are (things which I have changed from default):
divisions = 200,
time scale = 0.4,
vorticity = 4,
dissolve time = 100,
high resolution smoke divisions = 2,
noise method = FFT with a strength = 2

My questions are:

1. What settings/node setup do I need to change to get the smoke looking more smooth and realistic as shown in the first image?
2. How do I light it so that I get the defined shadows?  I tried using a Sun lamp, point lamp and area lamp none of which seem to cut the mustard.  At the moment I am back to using a point lamp which I've animated to move through the smoke but it doesn't generate the right shadows.  Interestingly the viewport seems to do it reasonably well but the render turns out quite different.

Comment: According to 2. Use HDR Environment map.

Comment: I'm not a blender expert but isn't a HDR Environment map a static light source?  In the animation it looks like a torch is being moved through the smoke

Comment: For moving light you can use sphere with emission shader. But to have more realistic smoke hdr should help. Also, could you provide your blend file?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on HDR lighting I will give that a spin.  Good point on the moving sphere with emission shader I didn't think of that one.  The blend file can be found here:
http://www.filedropper.com/untitled6
Let me know if you have trouble accessing

Comment: You can increase Light Path > Volume to something about 10 to improve lightning inside smoke. Also check my profile for my answers about smoke, there are some good informations.

Comment: I can't call the result from the first image as really realistic.. at least not really worth to be reproduced. You could start from some tuts like "Blender Cycles smoke". To make smoke thicker multiply its density, see [feature overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs). To lighten it up several lamps (as only one lamp is not good lighting) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Luke, increasing the Volume light paths to 10 helped a bit.  I'll check out your profile too